# Prompting for input too many times also trouble with array output

Tags: c++

Alright so my [assignment](http://pastebin.com/qx1haD9x) wants me to get information on 4 divisions of a company from the user. When I run and compile it it prompts for 8 divisions (like I said, I only want 4), also when it displays the information gathered to the screen it does not show a name for the different divisions. [Example](http://pastebin.com/qX2Vh0df)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 12;

struct Division
{
      char divName[SIZE]; // Division name
      double sales[4]; // Quarterly sales stored as an array
};



int main()
{
       void Intro();
       std::vector<Division> CreateCorporateFile();
       void DisplayCorporateSales();

       Intro();
       CreateCorporateFile();
       DisplayCorporateSales();


       system("PAUSE");
       return 0;
}

void Intro()
{
     cout<<"This program will prompt you to enter in quarterly sales for "
           "four different\ndivisions of a company.\n\n";
}


std::vector<Division> CreateCorporateFile()
{
    std::vector<Division> divArray;
    Division div;
    int x = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
    /*do {*/int quarter = 1;
          cout << "Enter the name of the division: ";
          cin >> div.divName;
          for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
          {
               cout << "Enter in the sales for quarter "<< quarter <<": ";
               cin >> div.sales[i];
               if(div.sales[i] > 0)
               {
                    quarter++;
               }
               else
               {
                    cout << "Sales are not allowed to be negative.\n";
               }
          }

        divArray.push_back(div);
        /*x++;
    } while(x < 4);*/
}
    return divArray;
}




void DisplayCorporateSales()
{
     Division div;

         std::vector<Division> divisions = CreateCorporateFile();
    for (size_t i=0; i<divisions.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Here are the quarterly sales for " << div.divName
        << ": \n";
        Division div = divisions[i];
        for(int j = 0, quarter = 1; j < 4; ++j, ++quarter)
        {
            cout << "Quarter "<< quarter << " sales: $"<< div.sales[j]
            <<"\n";
        }
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it asks double, is because you call `CreateCorporateFile` twice.

Either call it only in `main`, save the returned vector, and pass it to `DisplayCorporateSales`. **Or** don't call it in `main` at all.

I also recommend you use `std::string` for the string (name) instead of the `char` array.

Comment: Alright, I have been working on this far too long and am not seeing it. Could you kindly point out where I call it a second time, I have scoured over it and still nothing.

Comment: @Kobrien Almost the first thing you do in `DisplayCorporateSales`.

Comment: Ahh thank you. I have been up working on this for far too long and just want to get it done and over with. That did fix the problem with taking Create out of Main. But now the output is [this](http://pastebin.com/EkXV8Vw4) How would I implement that for the string instead of char.

Comment: That is because you are outputting the div.divName and not the divisions[i].divName